# e-TeX and \newfam allocation

Tags: pstricks, e-tex

If PSTricks is used with e-TeX (from the latest TeX Live distribution), it appears that only the 7 families 9 trough 15 are available to `\newfam`.  If PSTricks is used with tex (again, from the latest TeX Live distribution), the 8 families 8 through 15 are available.

The reason seems to be that PSTricks repeats some of the allocation macros from `plain.tex`.  The problem is illustrated by the code below.  The definition of `\alloc@` below is copied from the current TeX Live `plain.tex`.  If this is submitted to TeX, the numbers 7 and 8 are dutifully reported.  If submitted to e-TeX, the numbers 7 and 9 are reported.

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5{\global\advance\count1#1by\@ne
  \ch@ck#1#4#2% make sure there's still room
  \allocationnumber=\count1#1%
  \global#3#5=\allocationnumber
  \wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}}
\catcode`\@=12\relax

\newfam\nextfam  
\immediate\write16{\the\ttfam}  
\immediate\write16{\the\nextfam}  
\bye
```

This is a problem for me, because I have some much used font handling files which require the full 15 families.

Comment: pstricks doesn't allocate any fam but etex (if I remember correctly) includes etex.src which does redo the allocation macros (for the larger range of box registers etc) so re-inserting the plain tex allocation macros would break that.

Comment: or you could use xetex or luatex (which have 256b fam)

Comment: The assumption of whether `\count<whatever>` is the current value or the next one are different between `plain.tex` and `etex.src`. You therefore can't mix up the two approaches!

Comment: @JosephWright for reasons that aren't that clear pstricks re-inserts the plain tex one if it isn't running in latex

Comment: @david  I don't know why pstricks re-inserts the plain tex definition, but will ask Herbert Voss and report back.  He did patch pstricks.tex for me so that it tests for etex and does the appropriate reinsertion.  I assume it will get to CTAN at some point.

Comment: @JohnFrampton OK glad you got it working, feel free to self-answer so the question gets off the stack of unanswered ones:-)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, Etex revises the plain.tex allocation macros.  pstricks.tex did not properly account for this.

Herbert Voss has now added a test for Etex to PSTricks so that the proper definitions are made.  It has gone to CTAN, so it is available to all.